# How do I run commands from visual studio cross tool command prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a batch file from x86_x64 cross tools command prompt
here is my batch file content:

```
start cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"  && cmd /c nmake debug=0
```

at first its switching to "x86_x64 cross tools command prompt" but while running  next command (nmake debug=0) switching back to normal cmd prompt. Not sure whats causing this?

Thanks in advance
Ashok

Comment: `cmd /c` performs the command and then terminates the command instance. If you want it to stay open for the next command, use `cmd /k` instead. You also don't need `cmd /c` in the command for `nmake` if you want it to run in the same command window. For more info, type `cmd /?` at a command prompt.

Comment: How about `start cmd /c """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" && nmake debug=0"`

Comment: With `vcvarsall.bat` not all VS dependencies are loaded, so trying load `call "x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019.lnk" 
&& cd C:\MyCode
&& nmake debug=0 ` But problem with above it is successfully switched to `x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019` but not executing further commands  `cd C:\MyCode
&& nmake debug=0`. Is it possible to switch to a new command prompt and run commands  from cmd prompt!?

Comment: can't find any solution, any help ?